# Google Apps Script and HTML Service; how do I bring in Spreadsheet values to display on my .html page?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Using Google Apps Script and HTML Service how do I bring in specific cells of data into my index.html page?

Basically my 'getdata' function does get me spreadsheet data but my 'getdata2' needs a little help.  I am hoping someone might have and idea that might get me going.

I have some code that I think will help give you an idea of what I am hoping for.

index.html follows

```
 <H1>Hope to get data from a spreadsheet</H1>
<div id="myDataDiv">
<? var data = getData(); ?>
<?= data       ?>

</div>
<Hr>
<div id="myDataDiv2">
<? var data2 = getData2(); ?>
<?= data2.mySingleValue       ?><br />
<?= data2.mySingleValue2       ?>
</div>
```

code.gs follows

```
var submissioSSKey = '1Jyc2XmgQ7ffuRDpieT_DyJIUWVWi-9UUn2vAQqr_zJY';//this is an altered key
function doGet() {
      return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('index')
      .evaluate()
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function getData() {
  return SpreadsheetApp
 .openById(submissioSSKey) 
  .getActiveSheet().getRange("B3").getValue(); 
}

function getData2() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(submissioSSKey); 
var mySingleValue = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('B3').getValue(); //hoping for value 1 
var mySingleValue2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('B4').getValue(); //hoping for value 2

}
```

Comment: In the future when posting questions or answers you might want to replace values like `submissioSSKey` with fake values and include a note to that effect.

Comment: thanks Jason I added a note to the key line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function getData2() is not returning any value, so nothing is passed to the data2 variable in your HTML scriptlet.

Try this:

```
function getData2() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(submissioSSKey);
 var myValues = {}; 
 myValues["mySingleValue"] = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('B3').getValue(); //hoping for value 1 
 myValues["mySingleValue2"] = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange('B4').getValue(); //hoping for value 2
 return myValues;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that I've tested and works for me.

Only use one function.

```
function getData(argWhatCell) {
  Logger.log("argWhatCell: " + argWhatCell);

  var returnValue = SpreadsheetApp.openById("My Sheet ID").getActiveSheet().getRange(argWhatCell).getValue();
  Logger.log("returnValue: " + returnValue);
  return returnValue;
}
```

NOTE that the function `getData(argWhatCell)` must get a string passed to it that is the sheet cell you want to retrieve.
Use the same function `getData()` multiple times rather than having multiple functions.
Pass what cell to retrieve from the HTML.  You don't need a `getData2()` function.

```
<H1>Hope to get data from a spreadsheet</H1>
<div id="myDataDiv">
  <? var data = getData("B3"); ?>
  <?= data       ?>
</div>

<Hr>

<div id="myDataDiv2">
  <? var data2 = getData("B3"); ?>
  <?= data2       ?>

  <? var data3 = getData("B4"); ?>
  <?= data3       ?>
</div>
```

If you want to get all the data at once by running the function only once, you'll need to create an array, and return the array to the scriptlet.  Once the data is retrieved into the scriptlet, the variable that the data received the data can be accessed.

Comment: Sandy I am working with your solution; no success yet.  I'm not really understanding what you are telling me at this point in time. Hopefully it will click soon... you are definitely at a much higher level then I am.  Chris

Comment: Note the `Logger.log();` statements in the code.  You may need to debug the code line by line, and check the value of every variable in succession.  In the VIEW menu, choose LOGS to see what is printed to the log.